# Time evolution of a projected mixed state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator, time-evolution

Suppose a quantum system (non-interacting) at finite temperature ($\beta^{-1}$).  I want to know how to compute the transition probability between two degrees of freedom ($u$ and $v$) at two different times.

The system  starts ($t=0$) in a mixed state, described by 
$$
\hat \rho = \sum_l e^{-\lambda_l \beta} |\psi_l\rangle\langle \psi_l|/Z
$$
I projected  the mixed state into $|u\rangle$,  applying the projector 
$$
\hat P_u = |u\rangle\langle u|.
$$
Therefore 
at $t=0$, I have 
$$
\hat P_u \hat \rho \hat P_u.
$$
Because I want the transition probability in the future, I used the evolution operator
$$
\hat U(t_f) = \sum_n e^{-i\lambda_n \beta} |\psi_n\rangle\langle \psi_n|
$$ 
to evolve the mixed state
$$
\hat U(t_f)^\dagger\hat P_u \hat \rho \hat P_u \hat U(t_f).
$$
Then  I projected the  last operator into
  $|v\rangle$,

$$
\hat P_v \hat U(t_f)^\dagger\hat P_u \hat \rho \hat P_u \hat U(t_f)\hat P_v
$$

Computing the trace of the above operator,

$$
\mathrm{Tr}[\hat P_v \hat U(t_f)^\dagger\hat P_u \hat \rho \hat P_u \hat U(t_f)\hat P_v] ,
$$

I  get

$$
(\sum\limits_l \frac{e^{-\beta \lambda_l}\langle \psi_l|u\rangle\langle u|\psi_l\rangle}{Z})
(\sum\limits_m e^{-i\lambda_m t}\langle \psi_m|v\rangle\langle u|\psi_m\rangle)
(\sum\limits_n e^{i\lambda_n t}\langle \psi_n|u\rangle\langle v|\psi_n\rangle)
$$

Did I make any mistakes?

I expected some mixing between the time and temperature in the last equation, but if everything is right there is no mixing in that case.

Comment: Everything looks right,  Jitendras suggestion is basically a time reversal and won’t dramatically change anything.  What do you mean by a mixing of time and temperature?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of evolving is wrong. It should be
$\hat U(t_f)\hat P_u \hat \rho \hat P_u \hat U(t_f)^\dagger$.